# Firebase authentication - Unknown error while making a remote service call

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

We are using Firebase on Python 2.7 Standard google app engine for authentication. We are using firebase_admin==3.2.1 in our requirements.txt

We are trying to create a session cookie based on documentation [here][1] and [1] [here][2].

But we get the following error

('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(146 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(146 bytes read)) code : UNKNOWN message : Unknown error while making a remote service call: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(146 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(146 bytes read))

when executing this statement

```
  def post(self):
    logging.info(self.request.body)
    session_data = json.loads(self.request.body)
    
    # Get the ID token sent by the client
    id_token = session_data['idToken']
    expires_in = datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    session_cookie = firebase_admin.auth.create_session_cookie(id_token, expires_in=expires_in,app=None)
```

[Update]

We tried to execute this code to verify the id_token

```
     decoded_token = firebase_admin.auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
     uid = decoded_token['uid']
```

The above code executes without any error. We are able to verify the uid (from Firebase console).
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#python_1
[2]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth

Comment: Looks like you haven't vendored in the `requests-toolbelt` package and the App Engine monkeypatch. See https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#the-app-engine-standard-environment

Comment: thanks @HiranyaJayathilaka . That worked.

Answer (score 0):

We added this code to our controller1.py and it worked.

```
import requests
import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
```